# Split string into array of equal length strings

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I need split into smaller strings with an equal length of 6. I tried using:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(/(.{6})/)
```

But it returns an array with empty strings like so:

```
["", "abcdef", "", "ghijkl", "", "mnopqr", "", "stuvwx", ""]
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use `match` in conjunction with a global flag, instead of split. `{1,6}` is needed, to also include the last part of the matched string. Patterns are greedy by default, which means that as much is matched as possible. So, `.{1,6}` will only match less than 6 characters at the end of a string.

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.match(/.{1,6}/g);
```

Result:

```
["abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqr", "stuvwx", "yz"];
```

<sub>Note that the returned object is a true array. To verify:</sub>

```
console.log('.'.match(/./g) instanceof Array);  //true
```

Comment: Note that `.` does *not* match any character. It [ignores `Lineterminator`s](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.2.8). Use `[\s\S]` instead to make sure it works on multi-line strings.

Comment: instead of using [\s\S] you could use the s ("dotAll") flag