# Console.log alphabet with space every 3 letters javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'm learning JS and I have a challenge that I can't solve so far. I have to have the alphabet in an array like so... `var alphabet = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];` or `var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];`. I need to `console.log()` the alphabet as fallow...

```
a
ab
abc
abc d
abc de
abc def
abc def g
abc def gh
abc def ghi
```

So far I have the following code...

```
function stackLetter(l) {
    for (var index = 1; index < l[0].length; index++) {
        console.log(l[0].slice(0, index));
    }
}


stackLetter(alphabet);
```

The outcome so far...

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
abcdefg
abcdefgh
abcdefghi
abcdefghij
abcdefghijk
abcdefghijkl
abcdefghijklm
abcdefghijklmn
abcdefghijklmno
abcdefghijklmnop
abcdefghijklmnopq
abcdefghijklmnopqr
abcdefghijklmnopqrs
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

I'm still reading in the MDN about string manipulation but can't make it to work so far. How I can tweak my code to accomplish the outcome? I want to do this with vanilla JS.

Comment: What you get so far? Alphas without empty space?

Comment: first array makes no sense..is a single element array with one long string for that element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359905/split-string-into-array-of-equal-length-strings ?

Comment: The array in that way is part of the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function stackLetter(l) {
    for (var index = 1; index < l[0].length; index++) {
        var str = "";
        for(var j = 0; j < index; j++)
        {
            str += l[0][j];
            if(j % 3 == 0 && j != 0)
                str += " ";
        }
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: If statement  ☝️ 1 line?

Comment: `j % 3 == 0` means `j` modulo `3`. The modulo operator (`%`) return the rest of the division of the left operand on the right operand. So here we test if the rest of the division of `j` on `3` is `0`. That mean if `j` is 0 or 3 or 6 or 9 or ... the `j % 3` will be `0`. And of course we exclude the case of `j` equal to 0. by the way the `%` is the percentage character.

Comment: I mean you should test to see your result in jsbin/js fiddle first to whether it gives the expected output ;)

Comment: It work. Just fixed a problem `j < index` instead of `j < i`. Stupid mistake because I'm used to use `i` for loops and not `index`.

Comment: I don't know. I just Upvoted your question to get you close to 0 at least lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a space to your string after every 3rd letter:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b'...'y', 'z'];

function stackLetters(alphaArr) {
  var stackResult = ''; //initialize as empty string
  for (var i = 0; i < alphaArr.length; i++) { //iterate thru alphabet array
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i !== 0) { //every 3rd element
      stackResult += ' ' + alphaArr[i]; //prepend space and concatenate result
    } else {
      stackResult += alphaArr[i]; //concatenate result
    }
    console.log(stackResult); //log during each iteration current stackResult
  }
}
```

Comment: If statement && I != 0

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

function stackLetter(l) {
    l.forEach( function(l1, i1) {
        var str = '';
        for (var i2=0; i2<=i1; i2++) {
            str += l[i2]
            if ((i2+1) % 3 == 0) str += ' ';
        };
        console.log(str);
    } );
}


stackLetter(alphabet.split('')); //or pass the array directly
```

Results:

```
a
ab
abc 
abc d
abc de
abc def 
abc def g
abc def gh
abc def ghi 
abc def ghi j
abc def ghi jk
abc def ghi jkl 
abc def ghi jkl m
abc def ghi jkl mn
abc def ghi jkl mno 
abc def ghi jkl mno p
abc def ghi jkl mno pq
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr 
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr s
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr st
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu 
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu v
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vw
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx 
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx y
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

...or another approach using ES6 and regex (just for fun):

```
function stackLetter(_alphabet) { //receives a string

    _alphabet
        .match(/.{1,3}/g)
        .map((c) => c + ' ')
        .join('').split('')
        .forEach( (a,b,c) => console.log(c.slice(0,b).join('') ) )

}
```

Comment: @Gilbert regex is my second approach. Btw, should have mentioned in your question that you can't use regex.

Comment: I thought I did. All the answers are helpful for my learning process though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has an accepted solution, but I think this solution is more simple - rather than iterating through the loop and applying the spacing logic each time - do it one and insert the space before each third element creating a string with spaces. Then iterate through the list and display a substring with an increasing number of the modified string with a line break to give the stacked style.

```js
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  var str = '', spacer;
  for(i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0){var spacer = ' '} else {var spacer=''};
    str += spacer + alphabet[i];
  };
  console.log(str); //gives abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz

  for(a=0;a<=str.length;a++){
   var res = str.substr(0, a);
   console.log(res); //give results such as abc def ghi jkl mno
  }
```