# String to array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to convert a String '1234567' to Array
like this['123','456','7']

i have try this:

```
        let str='1234'
        let num=3;
        let temp='';
        let array=str.split('')
        let newArr=[];
        for(let i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
            if((i+1)%num!==0){
                temp+=array[i]
                
                    
            }else{
                temp+=array[i]
                newArr.push(temp)
                temp='';
            }
        }    
    console.log(newArr)
```

but it miss the 4

Comment: First result from googling for `javascript split string to equal parts` for me is [Split string into array of equal length strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8359905). Does it answer your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the logic for the split? Can you not use `s.match(/.{1,3}/g)`?

Comment: yes, but i can not how to put a num, like  s.match(/.{1,num}/g)

Comment: [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4234533)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the loop finishes, `temp` may be non-empty without having been added to `newArr`. One way to handle this would be to check for this scenario after the loop and handle accordingly.

```js
// after the for-loop
if (temp) {
    newArr.push(temp)
}
```